# WinForms - Capture key up before control

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, capture

I've got a form and am subscribing to the KeyUp event and handling the ALT key, this is working great but only when my form has the focus, if a control on the form has focus then this no longer works; what can I use to capture the keys when controls have focus? I'd rather not have to subscribe to every KeyUp event on every on the form controls...

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will setting the form's **KeyPreview** property to true work for you?

Comment: Yeah, KeyPreview property has always worked for me. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try overriding **ProcessCmdKey** from your form. This will be raised regardless of which controls have focus, so long as the form is active. You will have to do a little more work checking the keydata. Ex:

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if ((keyData & Keys.Alt) == Keys.Alt)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ALT");
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Comment: I was trying to prevent some arrow keys from getting through, and overriding ProcessCmdKey was the answer for me.  Thanks!